# CoAP PUT and POST method differentiation

Tags: server, coap

Can anyone help how to differentiate the incoming message structure of PUT and POST methods in CoAP protocol?

Or should we do some work in server c++ files ???

Comment: Everything related to the structure is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252.
Your question seems incomplete. You've mentioned server and C++ but is it relevant for your question?

Comment: The Server C++ file mentioned here is that of CoAP library.  We have a set of C++ file for CoAP Client and Server.

Answer (score 0):

Each CoAP message has a method code. It is 8 bit unsigned integer represented as `x.yy` where `x` is the 3 bit class and `yy` is 5 bit detail field.

You can use it to differentiate between PUT and POST.

Check out the RFC for the [message format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#section-3) and the [method code list](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#section-12.1.1).

For POST the code is 0.02 i.e. the byte is encoded as `0x02` while for PUT it is 0.03 so the byte is encoded as `0x03`.